# Segmentation fault with function pointer

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, function-pointers

File1.c:

```
Init()
{
    Add(MyLoop)
}

void MyLoop(bool)
{
    // does stuff
}
```

File0.c:

```
int main(void)
{
    Init();
    Run(false);
}
```

File2.c:

```
void (* mpfStateMachine)(bool);

void Run(bool Irrelevant)
{
    mpfStateMachine(Irrelevant);
}

void Add(void (* func)(bool))
{
    mpfStateMachine = func;
}
```

Note: I've ommited the header files, but you may assume the header files (and their #includes) are in order

When I run the above code, it gives me a segmentation fault.

When I comment out "mpfStateMachine(Irrelevant);" inside Run(), it compiles and runs fine.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [mre], and [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: A nice time to use a debugger.

Comment: @Sam, Object and functions lack declarations before their first use.  Add them.  Save time.  Enable all complier warnings.

Comment: Please post a [mre].  The missing ; after Add(MyLoop) is a syntax error.

Comment: I combined the 3 files and was not able to reproduce the issue after I fixed the syntax error and missing headers.  I.e. @chux-ReinstateMonica is probably right about missing declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the bug was completely unrelated. There was a bug inside MyLoop().

Thanks to Allan Wind for hinting I should reproduce it myself with a minimal example.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33035673)